# If I call addperiodicsync and autosync on the same account which one will be effective?

Tags: android, calendar

If for a particular calendar sync account in android I call following two in given order,

`ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account,CalendarContract.AUTHORITY, result, 120);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account,CalendarContract.AUTHORITY, true);`

What would be given priority ? As per documentation

*These periodic syncs honor the "syncAutomatically" and "masterSyncAutomatically" settings. Although these sync are scheduled at the specified frequency, it may take longer for it to actually be started if other syncs are ahead of it in the sync operation queue. This means that the actual start time may drift.*